# Three equal-width columns with margin

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a layout where I have three equal-wdith columns (33% width each). However, I want a 15px margin on either side of the middle column.

Please see this jsbin example I've created: http://jsbin.com/usiduy/edit
How can I get the blue column to sit on the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this css:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px; left: 50px;
    bottom: 30px; right: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc
}

#container > div {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#container div div {
    height:100%;
}
#container div div.a {
    background: red;
}
#container div div.b {
    background: green; margin:0 15px;
}
#container div div.c {
    background: blue;
}
```

using this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <div><div class="a">First</div></div>
        <div><div class="b">Second</div></div>
        <div><div class="c">Third</div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Great! Middle column was still smaller. Here's what I ended up doing: http://jsbin.com/usiduy/7/edit Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

**CSS:**

```
  .item.first { background: red;width: 33%;float:left; margin-right:15px}
  .item.middle { background: green; overflow:hidden;}
  .item.last { background: blue;width: 33%;float:right;margin-left:15px}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item first"></div>
        <div class="item last"></div>
    <div class="item middle"></div>

</div>
```

Check live example

### http://jsbin.com/usiduy/4/edit#html

**Updated:**

http://jsbin.com/usiduy/6/edit#html

Comment: These might look like they are equal width, but the middle one is in fact shorter in width.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean three equal width table columns in sum, you can create a table with three columns, then set padding-left: 15px and padding-right: 15px in the middle column (in td).

Comment: An easy simple solution, except if you want wrapping for small screens

Answer (score 0):

Because you are mixing fixed pixel widths with percentages, you need to calculate the 33% of the page width minus the 30px of margins *on the fly*.

This is a JavaScript solution, so a JavaScript savvy contributor should be able to help you out :)

Comment: Already done so, but the performance is absolutely terrible on resize. I was really hoping for a CSS solution.

 `var w = $(window).width() - 150;
 var article_width = w / 3;
 var article_height = $(window).height() - 110;
 $('#news article').css({'width':article_width, 'height':article_height});`